# Set-up template in Indesign for creep

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, print-production, imposition

How to set-up Indesign for creep/shingling on 116 page booklet?

Comment: Do you print the booklet yourself or will you use a commercial printer for this?

Comment: No, I will be using a commercial printer thanks

Comment: Hi Phill, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Did you Google this? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3):

It's the printer who calculates these things based on the type of paper (thickness), the imposition, the type of binding and the number of pages. There's no definite one-size-fits-all formula because of this. They will adjust the creep with their imposition software (eg. [Preps](http://graphics.kodak.com/US/en/Product/printing_workflow/Production_Planning/PREPS_Software/default.htm)).

**What you can do as a designer is to respect the minimum safe margin your printer suggests you.** For books, it looks good to have a 1/2" - 5/8" safe margin where the binding is. The thicker the book (eg.  more pages), the bigger the safe margin should be. A 116 pages book is not a big book. Printers also use different ways to do their imposition and calculate the creep (positive or negative creep), so in doubt, it's better to simply call the printer. Just so you know, with a small 116 pages book, the creep is very small and planing it in your layout isn't as vital as on big 300 pages books. When you use good safe margins, there's usually no problems.

If you need to print your booklet on your own printer, then you can refer to Adobe's help file to set up the creep in Indesign. It's quite rare a real creep will be required on "home printed projects" since it also requires other trimming equipment and some kind of production setup. The creep functionality in Indesign is not as precise as the one you'd find on Preps.

I don't suggest you to use the Indesign creep yourself if you use a commercial printer for your book. You should let the printer deal with the imposition and creep; simply provide him/her the print-ready files without any imposition.

https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/printing-booklets.html#understanding_creep

**Related:**

http://www.graphicdesignforum.com/forum/forum/graphic-design/printing-and-prepress/1530688-adjusting-an-indesign-document-for-creep

Comment: To go-junta. Thank you, you explanation is very precise and easy to understand.