# What are these two types of lay-flat binding called?

Tags: print-design, print-production, terminology, book, binding

I'm in the process of printing a book. I would like to use lay-flat binding. What are the following two types of lay-flat binding called?

Lay-flat binding type 1:

[image]

[image]

Lay-flat binding type 2

[image]

[image]

Please ignore the paper types (glossy in the example of lay-flat binding type 1, and matte in the example of lay-flat binding type 2).

Comment: The second looks like some sort of fancy boardbook bindind but head and tail bands are typically found in sewn binding... Do all pages seem like "centerfolds", with no hint of anything holding them together?

Comment: @curious thanks, all pages seem like "centerfolds", with no hint of anything holding them together. I had opened a random page.

Answer (score 3):

Both examples would be classified as **Sewn Binding**.

Individual signatures are sewn together before being sewn to each other. Glue is used to strengthen the spine after it's all stitched together, and finally a cover added.

Typically sewn binding can be more expensive, but it's also more durable than many other binding methods.

More info: https://blog.ironmarkusa.com/book-binding-sewn (random search result.)

Comment: Thanks! Is there any term to distinguish the two types of sewn binding pictured in the question?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt -- Essentially, the first example is stitched with **creep** in mind, the second does not compensate for creep. I don't think there's terminology other than this to describe the two samples. [Creep](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64043/set-up-template-in-indesign-for-creep) is typically *not* something the designer is concerned with because the thickness of the stock needs to be known to correctly calculate creep. Printer providers have tables of stock data for stuff like this.

Comment: Something bothers me about both. The second example is clearly glued back to back. That leaves every double page as a continuous sheet - something you don't get in sewn. Once glued, it *could* even be some form of manual perfect binding. The first bothers me for similar reasons, but I can't tie down quite what makes it 'odd'' other than the obvious triangular structure. It could also be perfect bound. I'd take a wild swing that you couldn't walk into snappy snaps & order either of those ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin In reality I *think* most sewn binding **is** also what could be considered Perfect Bound. They do glue the spine after the stitching. I think it's standard procedure... but it's not referred to as "perfect" in order to prevent confusion.

Comment: I wish the first was in focus. I'm betting it's a fine backing paper, perfect bound, with photographs stuck to each face. There would have to be some compensation in each leaf as it's bound, but that's the only way I can imagine the delicate hinge being made. I think both are hand-made.

Comment: … but… sewing doesn't give every double page a single sheet, only one in every 'clump' [too long ago, don't remember the terms]

Comment: @Tetsujin I think the term you are looking for is booklet or signature :)

Comment: Sewn can be just 1 signature or several signatures and then *those* are sewn (i.e. "block sewn"). I think the examples are really one of each. The top is block sewn best I can tell.

Comment: I don;t think these are sewn at all and certainly not perfect bound. I'll agree with an above poster that said they look handmade, glued editions, and may even be one-offs. Question - is there a copyright page with/without a publisher's logo?

Comment: You see the threading at the spine, right? Handmade or machine made, sewn binding is still sewn binding. I can Perfect Bind something at home, it doesn't make it any *less* Perfect Binding.

Comment: I see headbands - I don't see any sewing...

Comment: @JeffK there's no copyright page with/without a publisher's logo. They are one-offs (printing 1 photobook given by a customer).

Comment: Then my best guess is that these are custom, fully hand-glued editions. Can't really comment on the style but that triangular binding is really unique.

Comment: It's notched sewn/case bound. And it's *not* handmade. Jeff appears to be expecting something like [this](https://blog.johnroberts.com/hs-fs/hubfs/DSC_3718-2.jpg?width=600&name=DSC_3718-2.jpg) for sewn, but sewn binding doesn't have to "feature" the stitching. Case Binding is a sewn binding technique for hard covers.. there are *plenty* of example of these as sewn binging. [1](https://www.tps1.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/adhesivebind.jpg) [2](https://abgprint.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/hardcover-binding-1-copy.jpg) The notched sewn is rare but it's still sewn.

Comment: How one "doesn't see" the black thread in the top question image and the red/white thread in the lower question image is a mystery to me.